# oracle apex 5: how to navigate to some other page (not default home page) after login

Tags: redirect, oracle-apex

I'm using oracle apex 5.
From the application, I'm sending mails for different users with different page links based on user roles.

For example, my app_id is 222.

```
For an user: the url link sent to user mail id is <hostname>:<port>/apex/f?p=222:5
For a manager: the url link sent to user mail id is <hostname>:<port>/apex/f?p=222:7
```

In Chrome it works fine, as the user or manager goes to link and after login, they are redirected to respective pages as 5 or 7.
But in IE, it always goes to Home page which is 1.

I have tried with `APEX_CUSTOM_AUTH.LOGIN` in the after submit branch pl/sql procedure of login button as well (of the login page ).

```
BEGIN
    APEX_CUSTOM_AUTH.LOGIN (
        P_UNAME       => :P101_USERNAME,
        P_PASSWORD    => :P101_PASSWORD,
        p_session_id  => V('APP_SESSION'),
        p_app_page    => :APP_ID||':7'|| :p_session_id);
END;
```

Again it works good in chrome, but NOT in IE.
In IE, it always goes to home page. IE version is 11. Why in IE, it's not able to goto the page needed?. Please help.

(Chrome version 54. By the way how it works good in chrome?).

Comment: did you check the compatibility/emulation mode in IE 11. if it works as a lower version mode. you may live problems. as i know apex needs IE 9 as minimum reguirement.   https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/install.50/e39144/pre_require.htm#HTMIG380

Comment: An alternative solution is to create an onLoad branch on a common home page

Answer (score 0):

This is not academic solution but will work.

Set a parameter in your application to know if people comes from a mail or normal login.
Set a parameter in your application where you store the value from the link in the mail.

Now the magic, do a Dynamic Action on Page Load and use JS to redirect to the desired page, obviously the DA has to be conditional and the condition must be the parameter where you came from.